# Hyperlink to specific page in MS Word document

Tags: html, ms-word, hyperlink

Is it possible to link to a specific page in an MS Word document via a hyperlink in a webpage?

The best information I have been able to find is [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/310520) from Microsoft Support, but it only outlines how to link to a bookmark within a MS Word document rather than a page.

I am hoping that there is a method similar to linking to a page within a PDF as outline [here](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/317/317300.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlikely since Word does not store page boundaries in documents but re-paginates every time a document is opened.

Comment: I figured it would be something like that. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Bookmark the page on the Word document to link to.

Here's a reference:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310520

Comment: This answer refers to a Microsoft document that explains how to link to create a bookmark in a Word document and how to link to it in HTML. However, this seems to be outdated information, as we can infer from the documents it links to. Anyway, the approach does not work in modern browsers, partly since they often do not directly open a Word file but just download it, to be opened by the user, and the bookmark information seems to get lost in the process.